# un-localizing user input in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I have a rails form where the user inputs localized data (e.g. currency values like 12,40 instead of 12.40). How do I un-localize this to put into the database?

Answer (score 2):

I've used the money gem before with good results. It supports localization and parsing of input based on currency

Comment: and here's the github for it:

Comment: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/wiki/Ruby-on-Rails-(Money.gem-3.0.3-and-later)

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the link, I'm very bad about not linking to things I reference.